# Any way to make Tailwind rotate transition work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, css-transitions

I am trying to smoothly rotate this `chevron-icon`:

```
<div
  class="w-[18px] ml-6 mr-2 text-slate-500 transition-all"
  :class="{ 'rotate-180': store.accountMenu }">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path
      fill="none"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="2"
      d="M20 6L10 16l10 10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

by using the tailwind `transition-all` class and a `rotate-180` class that gets applied conditionally via `vue 3 condition`. `store.accoutnMenu` is just an imported reactive function with a boolean property. The transition works but only when the icon rotates back from right to left, not when it is supposed to initially rotate left to right.

Comment: Applying `transition-transform` ( + `ease-linear` if you want linear transition fn) + conditional `rotate-180` should be [enough](https://play.tailwindcss.com/14ixMn5qPJ). The described behavior probably has to do with the `v-if`/`v-else`. Please provide a *runnable* [mcve] actually reproducing the bug.

Comment: @tao I've replaced the vue component with plain svg content but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `transform` class.

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/petertsoisstuff/pen/zYmjjqJ?editors=1010):

```js
<div
  class="w-[18px] ml-6 mr-2 text-slate-500 transition-all transform"
  :class="{ 'rotate-180': store.accountMenu }">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path
      fill="none"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="2"
      d="M20 6L10 16l10 10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```